# CSS max-height animation on click -

Tags: css, css-transitions

I've used CSS animation of Max-height attributes before but I have never noticed that if the max-height attribute is very big and transition time is very long that I get a strange behavior in my transition (especially on transition-out the actual transition only starts a while after pressing the button

```js
function toggleDetails() {
  var classList = document.getElementById("menu").classList.value;

  if (classList.indexOf("show") !== -1) {
    document.getElementById("menu").classList.remove("show");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("menu").classList.add("show");

  }
}
```

```css
#menu #list {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 15s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #d5d5d5;
}

#menu.show #list {
  max-height: 50000px;
  transition: max-height 15s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <a>hover me</a>
  <ul id="list">
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="openDetails" onclick="toggleDetails()">
  <a id="shoreMOre">Shore more</a>
</div>
```

Is there any way to finetune this properly? My main problem is that the content of this section varies a lot.

Comment: Does your `hover` do anything. It's a bit confusing.

Comment: Try change your `max-height: 50000px;` to `max-height: 100%;`.

Comment: @noob no hover does not. It was just leftover from an earlier trial. max-height: 100% doesn't do a change